# Which one is correct "United's stadium" or "United' stadium"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

What is the correct way to put the apostrophe. the doubt is with "stadium" because it starts with 's'.
E.g:

"United's stadium" or "United' stadium"

PS: I need to know why (with grammatical explanation and reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"United's stadium" is the correct spelling, since United is a (one) company and hence thought of as one (singular).

[Forming the possessive](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/forming-possessive/) - EF

> To form the possessive, add apostrophe + s to the noun. If the noun is
>   plural, or already ends in s, just add an apostrophe after the s.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter if "United" is singular or plural, because it doesn't end in "s" anyway. Even if you'd say "Manchester **United are** playing today", you'd say "Manchester **United's** stadium is empty".

Answer (score 3):

The possessive clitic is almost always *'s*. The only exceptions are plurals already ending in *-s* (eg *the boys' caps*), and some names ending in *-s* (eg *James' book*).

So there is *always* an "s" either before or after the apostrophe (rarely both).

Those rare plurals which don't end in *-s* take the usual *'s* (eg *the children's caps*), so even if you choose to treat *United* as plural (which British English often does) the possessive clitic is still *'s*.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification

Comment: For singular proper nouns ending in *s*, it's a matter of style; *The Chicago Manual of Style* goes with *James's*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: yes, I decided to ignore that issue, since it doesn't affect my answer.

Comment: It's common—not rare—to have an *s* both before or after the apostrophe—if you account for names ending in *s*.

Answer (score 1):

"United's stadium" is the stadium belonging to "United".  "United Stadium" is the stadium which bears that name.  "United' stadium" is improper punctuation.